# Highlighting innermost HTML element

Tags: jquery, html

I want to highlight the innermost HTML element on which my mouse pointer is. Since my page have scroll bars, using x,y coordinates will not help as an element will have different x,y positions on my screen depending on how much I scroll.

How do I achieve this using jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `mousemove` event with [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) to determine what element is the mouse is currently over.

Here's a simple example:

```js
$("html").on("mousemove", "*", function(e) {
  $(".highlight").removeClass("highlight");
  $(e.target).addClass("highlight");
});
```

```css
div {
  border: solid 1px black;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.a {
  height : 100px;
  width: 200px;
}

.b {
  height : 40px;
  width: 40px;
}

.c {
  height : 25px;
  width: 25px;
}

.highlight {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a">
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="b">
    <div class="c"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```